# border-radius is not applied to img element

Tags: rounded-corners, css, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to set a border-radius in IE 10 that does not work, but does work in IE 9. The problem is when I define a radius for only the upper-left corner of an image, the image is not clipped around the border-radius.

BAD:

```
<img style="border-radius: 14px 0px 0px 0px" alt="" src="">
```

Now, if I add a second border-radius to either the upper-right or lower-left, then the upper-left radius is applied.

GOOD:

```
<img style="border-radius: 14px 1px 0px 0px" alt="" src="">
```

This URL demonstrates the problem and adds reference images for those not using IE 10.

http://gamma.tiedtheleader.com/border-radius.htm

UPDATE 9/30:
I heard back from Microsoft on the Connect site, and they confirmed that they were able to reproduce the issue and are investigating it further.

Comment: @dystroy: Not anymore; IE10 went RTM together with Windows 8 last month. However it isn't yet available for Windows 7. I'm assuming it will become available once Windows 8 is released to the public next month.

Comment: @BoltClock So can we install IE 10 on our PC's or it needs windows 8? please provide some link.( i'm at office right now. cant install anything here)

Comment: At the moment, IE10 RTM is only available on Windows 8 RTM.

Comment: I've added a link to the IE Feedback Board, https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/765155/border-radius-is-not-applied-to-img-element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had the same problem with rounded corners not being applied in IE 10 on images.
Originally I had this:

```css
border-radius: 45px 0 45px 0;
```

with had as a result no borders at all, changing one of the 0 border-radius's made my border radius show up again.

At the end I applied this style:

```css
border-radius: 45px 0.1px 45px 0.1px;
```

Which has no side effects in other browsers, but I have back rounded corners in IE 10

Answer (score 0):

Try `border-top-left-radius: 14px`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know most browsers won't let you clip an image with rounded borders. (And even if IE10 does it might look weird in other browsers). The simplest solution is to use a nested div and set the image as background:

HTML

```
<div class="imageborder">
  <div id="image1"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.imageborder {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#image1 {
  background-image: (yourimage);
}
```

You might have to set the height the div manually for it to display.

Comment: border-radius on img tags works with IE9, Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.  This seems like a regression bug with IE 10.